# How to save as only last row of excel data in excel vb?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to ask one question.
I wrote a simple code where I click a Save button and then save as the excel file in "C:\new folder\". The problem I have now is how to save the last row of the original excel sheet in "C:\new folder\" if I add new row in original excel sheet.
I want the sheet which will be saved to contain only one row, from original excel sheet.

```
Sub Increment() 
   Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim Path As String
   Dim FileNane1 As String
   Dim FileName2 As String
   Path = "C:\new folder\"
   Call Increment
   FileNane1 = Range("A1").Value
   FileName2 = Range("B1")

   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileNane1 & "-" & FileName2 & ".xls"

End Sub
```

The above saves the entire excel sheet in "C:\new folder\" where I need only last row.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Create new book, pull last line from source book, save new book.

Answer (score 0):

Although it sounds like Greg's code may work for you (assuming that you figured out why the file was not saving correctly) it is more efficient to avoid using the `.Select` method except when absolutely necessary.

You were very close to functional with your original code, and could do what you want by adding just four lines to your original code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim FileName2 As String

    Path = "C:\new folder\"
    Call Increment
    FileName1 = Range("A1").Value
    FileName2 = Range("B1")

    '~~>find and copy the last row
        Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy

    '~~>add a new workbook and paste the content before saving
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & FileName1 & "-" & FileName2 & ".xls"

    '~~>close the new workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little confused on exactly what you want to do, but this should get you pretty close (assuming I understand correctly). This will select the last row of text, assuming there are no empty cells in Column A between A1 and the last row.

```
Sub SaveLastLine()

    'Variable declaration
        Dim WB As Workbook, _
            filename As String

        'Turn off screen updating and alerts
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'Make a copy of the last line of active sheet
        newName = ActiveSheet.Name
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("A1").Select
        Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
        filename = newName & ".xlsx"
        WB.SaveAs filename:="C:\New Folder\" & filename, FileFormat:=51

        'Restore screen updating and alerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's helpfully but I still have error to the line of Cells.Select in the above codes. When I press save button I'm asked to debug if yes it displays error message Run-Time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed. Except that it copies last row correctly but it does not save it in "C:\New Folder\". Is there someone who can help us to solve this question?.